# Tkinter can't change object(button)color with Command what am I missing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make buttons with a for loop the runs a command to change that button color.

This works but only changes one button.

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter.colorchooser import *
top=Tk()
buttonlist=[]
button_counter=0
def change_color():
    #change button color
    color=askcolor()
    color=color[1]
   buttonlist[0].configure(bg=color)

how_many_times=range(2)
y=25

for num in how_many_times:
   buttonlist.append(Button(width=5, 
  relief=SUNKEN, bg="Black", 
  command=change_color))
    buttonlist[button_counter].place(x=10, y=y)
    y=y+100
    button_counter=button_counter+1 
top.mainloop()
```

This doesn't work. For one it's makes me change the color before the button is created. Also gives me an error.

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter.colorchooser import *
top=Tk()
buttonlist=[]
button_counter=0

def change_color(button_number):
        #change button color
    color=askcolor()
    color=color[1]
    buttonlist[button_number].configure(bg=color)




how_many_times=range(2)
y=25
for num in how_many_times:
    buttonlist.append(Button(width=5, 
        relief=SUNKEN, bg="Black", command=change_color(button_counter)))
    buttonlist[button_counter].place(x=10, y=y)
    y=y+100
    button_counter=button_counter+1
top.mainloop()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File  "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/temp_iiec_codefile.py", line 19, in <module>
 buttonlist.append(Button(width=5, relief=SUNKEN, bg="Black", command=change_color(button_counter)))
 File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/temp_iiec_codefile.py", line 11, in change_color
buttonlist[button_number].configure(bg=color)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: use `print(button_number)` before `buttonlist[button_number].configure(bg=color)` and you will see why you have error `list index out of range` - because `button_number` is bigger then you have items on list.

Comment: `command=` needs callback - it means function name without `()` and parameters. If you have `command=function()` then it executes `function()` at start and you get `command=resutl_from_function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`command=` expect `callback` - it means function's name without `()`

You have to use lambda to assign function with parameters. But `lambda` inside `for` loop needs also `n=num` to use correct values in function. without this it will use last value from `for` loop in all buttons. And this value can be bigger then number of items on list - and it can give error `list index out of range`

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.colorchooser as tkcolorchooser

# --- functions ---

def change_color(button_number):
    #change button color
    color = tkcolorchooser.askcolor()
    color = color[1]
    buttonlist[button_number].configure(bg=color)

# --- main ---

buttonlist = []
y = 25

top = tk.Tk()

for num in range(2):
    b = tk.Button(width=5, relief="sunken", bg="Black",
               command=lambda n=num:change_color(n))
    b.place(x=10, y=y)
    buttonlist.append(b)
    y += 100

top.mainloop()
```